# How do I find the time complexity of this recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, partitioning

Dynamic programming algorithm of partitioning an array into k subsets with equal sum

```
bool checker(int nums[], bool visited[], int n, int index, int sum, int k)
{
    if(k==1)
        return true;
    if(sum==target&&checker(nums,visited,n,0,0,k-1))
    for(int i=index;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sum+nums[i]<=target&& !visited[i])
        {
            visited[i]=true;
            if(checker(nums,visited,n,index+1,sum+nums[i],k))
                return true;
                visited[i]=false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will help https://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/time-and-space-complexity-of-recursive-algorithms

Comment: Using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) might work.

Comment: From first sight it's n^h where h is the number of recurssive calls to reach the answer ( depth of the recurssive tree ), however it also depends on the if statements, so as mentioned in the comments it's better to use master theorem.